# Как изменить цвет текста и фона для всплывающей подсказки QToolTip?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Цвет текста и фона кнопки задавал так:

```
button->setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;");
```

Задал для кнопок всплывающие подсказки:

```
button->setToolTip("tooltip");
```

Пытался через QPalette:

```
QPalette palette;
palette.setColor(QPalette::Inactive,QPalette::ToolTipText,"#000000");
button->setPalette(palette);
```

Но не работает. Цвет шрифта очень бледный (такой же как у текста кнопки, но тот на тёмном фоне), что почти не виден. Подскажите, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
button->setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton { background-color:#000000; color:#ffffff; }"
    "QToolTip { color: #ffffff; background-color: #00ff00; border: 0px;"
);
```

Comment: Alexander , а так сработает:  `setToolTip('''
            <h3>This is a</h3> 
            <h1 style="background-color: #7777ff; color: red;">Button</h1> 
            <h2 style="color: blue;">widget</h2>
        ''')`

Comment: `QToolTip { ... }` не работает, но зато если поместить в `QPushButton { ... }`, то цвета для `QToolTip` не наследуются от `QPushButton`.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον  проверьте пожалуйста на `c++` мой ответ.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον, УМВР...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, я любитель `PyQt5`и там я могу вставить
подмножество HTML для определения расширенного текста.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QToolTip, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):                                   
        super().__init__()

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 12))
        
        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.setToolTip('''
            <h3>This is a</h3> 
            <h1 style="background-color: #7777ff; color: red;">Button</h1> 
            <h2 style="color: blue;">widget</h2>
        ''')
        btn.move(50, 50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()                            
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут же по c++ вопрос, а не python

Comment: @dIm0n я же написал, извините и попросил проверить работаетл-ли мой ответ на `c++`

Comment: @S.Nick, работает, спасибо. Я не могу 2 ответа поставить как решение.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον  а я могу вам поставить вам `+`, за то что вы проверили мой вариант.